# Find the threshold value such that the limit is $0$ or $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits

Lets define $g(x,f,m)$ (very similar to binomial distribution), where $0 \leq f \leq 1$:
$$g(x,f,m) = x^{mf}(1-x)^{m-mf}$$
Find an analytical solution for the threshold $f_t$ for which the limit:
$$\lim_{m \to \infty}\frac{g(a_1,m,f)}{g(a_2,m,f)+10*g(a_3,m,f)}$$
goes to $\infty$ if $f>f_t$ and goes to $0$ if $f<f_t$, given some parameters $0 \leq a_1, a_2, a_3 \leq 1$. The exact problems is for any $a_1$ given $a_2=\frac{1}{3}$ and $a_3=\frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** This ratio is $R=\dfrac{h(a_1,f)^m}{h(a_2,f)^m+10\cdot h(a_3,f)^m}$ with $h(a,f)=a^f(1-a)^{1-f}$ hence 
$$
R\to0\iff h(a_1,f)\lt\max\{h(a_2,f),h(a_3,f)\},
$$ 
and 
$$
R\to+\infty\iff h(a_1,f)\gt\max\{h(a_2,f),h(a_3,f)\}.
$$
Now one should study the function $f\mapsto h(a,f)$ for each fixed value of $a$ and deduce when each condition holds.

Comment: Does that imply that there is a value for which $R \to const$?

Comment: No this does not imply what you say, but what you say is true as well, when $f$ is such that $h(a_1,f)=\max\{h(a_2,f),h(a_3,f)\}$.

Comment: So the threshold $f_t$ is one of the solutions to the equations $h(a_1,f) =  h(a_2,f)$ and $h(a_1,f) = h(a_3,f)$, for which that function has higher value then the other for the concrete constants. Thanks very much, I should have treated them as constants in the first place.